# Android MaterialCardView cut corner style

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-components, materialcardview

I used a **MaterialCardView**

> I've given it a Cut Corners style

But the **views** are far from the corners

[IMAGE: Image spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdJCX.jpg)

It also I used the following code:

```
app:cardPreventCornerOverlay="true"
```

But it does not clip the corner

[IMAGE: not croped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbGgL.jpg)

Can anyone help me?

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
   android:id="@+id/topLayout"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:clipChildren="true"
   app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBackground"
   app:cardElevation="1.5dp"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigationBar"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
   app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/CardView.Shape.Cut">

   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginStart="-21dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="-21dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="-21dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="-21dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/topLayout"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/topLayout"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/topLayout"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/topLayout">

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="210dp"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:src="@drawable/photo_profile" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

[IMAGE: from top code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lfnO.png)

if use of:

```
app:cardPreventCornerOverlay="true"
```

[IMAGE: cardPreventCornerOverlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uDyl.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ShapeableImageView` from the material components library and give it the same `shapeAppearance` as the card, so the corners match.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView.java

It might only be avaialble as an alpha version though.

Comment: Please see again last edit of question and 2 more **photo**, i need this. [material.io - link](https://material.io/design/material-studies/shrine.html#about-shrine)

Comment: Did you try to use the `ShapeableImageView` ?

Comment: The problem is that I don't need **ImageView** and then the **ViewPager** will fit there.

Comment: Then I don't know. You can try to define and outline and clip with that https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping